# Running Rserve R

Tags: r

I am trying to run Rserve() on R to use R code in Tableau. Could you please help me with the error below? I am not very used to code and I've been struggling..(I use Mac)

```
> library(Rserve)
> Rserve(args="--no-save")
Starting Rserve:
 /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R CMD /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/Rserve/libs//Rserve --no-save 
R version 4.0.5 (2021-03-31) -- "Shake and Throw"
Copyright (C) 2021 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.
  Natural language support but running in an English locale
R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.
Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.
[Previously saved workspace restored]
Rserv started in daemon mode.
##> SOCK_ERROR: bind error #48(address already in use)
```

Comment: It sounds like the port number is already in use. Do you have another instance of Rserve running on that machine? I think the default is `Rserve(args="--no-save", port=6311)`. Try a different port number instead.

Comment: I am not sure. I killed all PINs that uses port=6311. But when I run Tableau, I keep getting the same error message.

Comment: Is there a specific port number I can use? I tried other port numbers but the results are the same.